# Signal/Slots with VIsual studio and Qt plugin

Tags: visual-studio-2012, qt5

i have this issue with slots and signals in visual studio 2012 with Qt plugin. When i compile the qt project, it shows the error:

> moc_mainwindow.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   "public: void __thiscall MainWindow::onUpdate(class QString)"
>   (?onUpdate@MainWindow@@QAEXVQString@@@Z) referenced in function
>   "private: static void __cdecl MainWindow::qt_static_metacall(class
>   QObject *,enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)"
>   (?qt_static_metacall@MainWindow@@CAXPAVQObject@@W4Call@QMetaObject@@HPAPAX@Z)

these are my classes:

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QString>

namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:
    void onUpdate(QString info);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QTextEdit *textEdit;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QString>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

MainWindow::onUpdate(QString info) {
    //ui->textEdit->append(info);
}
```

some help? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

I've included the Generated Files folder in the project solution.
thanks anyway!